# I want to fetch time column from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch time column from mysql database and to compare with current time. It should execute only if it matches with the current time. I am new to php. [This is my Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVy2F.png)

What I tried is

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$today = date("h:i a")
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE time = $today";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // execute you code
} else {

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

But the problem is in my table hyphen and 'or' symbol exists, I dont know how to compare??
Is it possible to compare the time like this format??

Datatype for timings column is longtext

Comment: What is  `|` And `-` After Time ?

Comment: Have you tried to compare with `LIKE`

Comment: '-' means available time like 10:00 AM -(to) 1:00PM and ' | ' means next session available time like 05:00 PM - 08:00PM

Comment: @NavdeepSingh NO.. How to do that. Please give a clue

Comment: Please tell can we do like this or not??

Comment: - and | does not any sense.

Comment: @HarshBarach Means i didnt get you

Comment: don't use - and |

Comment: @HarshBarach Then which is the alternate way??

Comment: remove hyphen and or symbol from the database table and try to compare.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE time LIKE '%".$today."%'"; try this

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to simply change the way for time storing in the database. Store the time in UNIX TIMESTAMP. I have worked with your code.

mysql to insert as UNIX TIMESTAMP

```
$sql = "INSERT into `Table_name` set time = time()";
```

Your code with modification in **$today = time();**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$today = time();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE time = '".$today."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // execute you code
} else {

}

$conn->close();
?>
```